# Noobie needs help debugging simple python/django code. Why won't this view work?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to complete the simple exercise near the top of the page here: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07/.  When the user goes to mysite.com/meta/ I want to display a simple html table on the page showing the HTTPRequest meta data.

In my `urls.py` file I have:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from mysite.views import display_request_meta_data

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^meta/$', display_request_meta_data),
)
```

In my `views.py` file I have:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def display_request_meta_data(request):
    meta_data = request.META.items()
    meta_data.sort()
    for x in meta_data
        # print x  # wasn't working, so I tried using a logger instead.
        logger.error(x)
    t = get_template('http_meta_data_table.html')
    html = t.render(Context(*meta_data_dict))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

In my templates directory I have a file called `http_meta_data_table.html` which contains the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTTP Meta Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        {% for key, value in meta_data_dict %}
            <tr><td>{{key}}</td><td>{{value}}</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
def display_request_meta_data(request):
    meta_data = request.META.items()
    meta_data.sort()
    for x in meta_data: # you were missing a semi column
        # print x  # wasn't working, so I tried using a logger instead.
        logger.error(x)
    t = get_template('http_meta_data_table.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'meta_data': meta_data})) # the dict doesn't exitst
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

In html, the dict doesn't exist either:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTTP Meta Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        {% for key, value in meta_data %}
            <tr><td>{{key}}</td><td>{{value}}</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

This has really nothing to do with django, these are very basic error. Learning programming while using a framework is a bad idea IMO. You should learn the basics before, or your learnin curve is going to look like a straigth wall.

Django is an easy framework to learn, but it assumes you know Python.

Comment: Very true. Learn you a Python first. I found Dive Into Python (http://www.diveintopython.net/toc/index.html) quite good; YMMV.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I don't know python yet -- switching over from java after six years.  But the only way I know to really learn a language is to dive in and start building a real project, so that's what I am doing.  So far I'm finding django incredibly intuitive, in spite of the fact that it is my first time grappling with python.

Comment: I know it's hard to switch from a language to another. Espacially, java and python are very different beasts. Play with some scripts before: scrap web page, batch rename files, there is always some use you can put into python before starting with django. Or at least, start with a micro framework, not something as rich as Django (even if it is my favorite). Bottle is nice. You wouln't recommand somebody learning java to start by coding a tomcat servlet, would you ?

Answer (score 0):

`meta_data_dict` is undefined. You probably was to pass `meta_data` to `t.render`

Comment: Thanks.  Fixed that, but it still isn't working.  An error message tells me that I have a syntax error at the line that reads `for x in meta_data`.  I'm completely new to python, so I must not understand how to loop through a list.